# Angular 2: How to use JavaScript Date Object with NgModel two way binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular 2 and I have this code:

JS, this code initiates the employee-variable for the template:

```
handleEmployee(employee : Employee){
        this.employee = employee;
        this.employee.startDate = new Date('2005/01/01');
        console.log(this.employee);
    }
```

Template:

```
...
<div>
    <label>Start date: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="employee.startDate" type="date" name="startDate"/>
  </div>
  <div>
...
```

Other data like firstname is displayed correctly. But for the date I just get:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

In the input element, which should be a date.

How can I do this?

Comment: When is `handleEmployee` called? Is `employee.startDate` initialized when the component is created (in the constructor or with the variable declaration)?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

### UPDATE:

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwy6ly)

when I wrote this answer [**DatePipe**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) did not exist, now you can just do this

```html
<input [ngModel]="startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" type="date" name="startDate"/>
```

---

`

---

### Old Answer:

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpQIjQWhrjq7bbFZBa08?p=preview)

You need to convert `date object` in the `input type="date"` format which is `yyyy-mm-dd`, this is how it will work

**Template:**

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="humanDate" type="date" name="startDate"/>
```

**Component (TS):**

```ts
export class App {
  startDate: any;

  constructor() {
    this.startDate = new Date(2005, 1, 4);
  }

  set humanDate(e){
    e = e.split('-');
    let d = new Date(Date.UTC(e[0], e[1]-1, e[2]));
    this.startDate.setFullYear(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate());
  }

  get humanDate(){
    return this.startDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's maybe because it's written in `TS` but you are using `JS`. Moreover I just showed you how to bind a `date object` with `NgModel` because I don't understand how you are using it. Tweak it as per your requirement

Comment: I had to modify this to use `parseInt(e[1] -1 )` for the month, otherwise it would add a month on every time I chose a date. I guess this is because the month is zero - indexed in the Date constructor.

Comment: thanks @dafyddPrys.  I updated the answer and PLUNKER, there was another issue caused by timeZone, now it should work perfectly. Just invalid dates are needed to be handled.

Comment: @A_Singh I had a further problem accounting for local timezone offsets being ignored in the ISOString. I had to calculate a time zone offset : `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ;` and then use that offset to print out the date : `return (new Date(this.endDate.getTime() - tzOffset)).toISOString().slice(0,10);` .... With that, I also didn't need to add 1 ti the day when setting `setFulYear`

Comment: @A_Singh your code works, except for the + 1 in last argument of setFullYear. It needs a 1..31 value, and getUTCDate returns a 1..31 value. Lose the "+ 1"

Comment: plunker doesn't work, is set humandate assigment of type string is not assignable to parameter of type number in Date.UTC for e[0], e[1]

Comment: ...works for me under Angular 4. Ensure ngModel is without "()" -> oneWay binding and also ensure you're using (ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" then it works for me as described by Ankit Singh. thx

Comment: Working fine on browser but date format is not getting changed on android device.

Comment: won't work with locatization. for instance german date has `dot` instead of `dash` - the first split would fail

Comment: Updated answer works perfectly - clear and concise too

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. It will change the data type of `startDate` from `Date` to `string`, as soon as you select a date.

Comment: Thanks Ankit I never know you could set the value of the model with this syntax: "(ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" - good to know (thumbs_up)

Answer (score 22):

Read [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) and [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#ngModel)
and my deсision:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="myDate" [ngModel]="myDate | date:'y-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="myDate = $event" name="birthday">
```

Comment: OP should _read your desicion_? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @bub Perhaps the answer is not complete. _This is my first experience_. But in the pages of the official documentation has a detailed explanation of how to use ngModel and what it consists of.

Comment: You have had a great answer, simple e efficient. It's work perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

FormControls (both template-driven and reactive) subscribe for values and write values via Directives that implement `ControlValueAccessor`. Take a look at the relevant method [selectValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L140), which is used in all necessary directives. Normal input controls (e.g. `<input type="text">`) or textareas are handled by the [DefaultValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts). Another example is the [CheckboxValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts) which is applied to checkbox input controls.

The job isn't complicated at all. We just need to implement a new value accessor for date input controls.
`DateValueAccessor` is a nice name:

```js
// date-value-accessor.ts

import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export const DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValueAccessor),
  multi: true
};

/**
 * The accessor for writing a value and listening to changes on a date input element
 *
 *  ### Example
 *  `<input type="date" name="myBirthday" ngModel useValueAsDate>`
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[useValueAsDate]',
  providers: [DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.valueAsDate']) onChange = (_: any) => { };
  @HostListener('blur', []) onTouched = () => { };

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  writeValue(value: Date): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'valueAsDate', value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }
}
```

We attach the `DateValueAccessor` to the multi-provider `DATE_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, so that [selectValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-beta.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L140) can find it.

The only question is, which selector should be used. I decided for an opt-in solution.
Here the DateValueAccessor selects on the attribute "useValueAsDate".

```html
<input type="date" name="myBirthday" ngModel useValueAsDate>

OR

<input type="date" name="myBirthday" [(ngModel)]="myBirthday" useValueAsDate>

OR

<input type="date" formControlName="myBirthday" useValueAsDate>
```

It is also possible to fix the default implementation.
The following selector would activate the feature magically.

```js
// this selector changes the previous behavior silently and might break existing code
selector: 'input[type=date][formControlName],input[type=date][formControl],input[type=date][ngModel]'
```

But please be aware, that this might break existing implementations that rely of the old behaviour. So I would go for the opt-in version!

### It's all on NPM and Github

For your convenience, I created the project [`angular-data-value-accessor`](https://github.com/JohannesHoppe/angular-date-value-accessor) on Github.
There is also a NPM package available:

```
npm install --save angular-date-value-accessor
```

Then just import the module via NgModule:

```js
// app.module.ts

import { DateValueAccessorModule } from 'angular-date-value-accessor';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DateValueAccessorModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can apply the "useValueAsDate" to your date input controls.

### Demo

Of course, there is a demo at:
http://johanneshoppe.github.io/angular-date-value-accessor/

Comment: Great stuff! Could this work for ng2-Bootstrap directives? [btnRadio] uses a string, so binding fails for ngModel properties that are number (enums).

Comment: haven't tested this for ng2-Bootstrap, but generally you can do pretty much  by implementing your  own `ControlValueAccessor `

Answer (score 3):

I began trying to implement Ankit Singh's solution and ran in to a few problems with validation and timezone stuff. (Even after trying the suggestions in the comment section of that answer)

Instead I chose to utilize moment.js to handle the transforming between string and date using ISO8601 format date strings. I've had great results in the past using moment.js so this was not a difficult decision. Seems to be working well for me, hopefully someone else finds this useful.

**For my Angular 2 app I ran npm install --save moment and then turned Ankit's solution into a wrapper around a js Date object:**

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class NgDate {

    date: any;

    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    set dateInput(e) {
        if (e != "") {
            var momentDate = moment(e, moment.ISO_8601).toDate();
            this.date = momentDate;
        }
        else {
            this.date = null;
        }
    }

    get dateInput() {
        if(this.date == null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        var stringToReturn = moment(this.date).format().substring(0, 10);
        return stringToReturn;
    }
}
```

Then for the HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="someDate" [(ngModel)]="ngDateModel.dateInput"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer lacks a function call to transform input date string to Date object. So this:

```
(ngModelChange)="startDate = $event"
```

Should be something like:

```
(ngModelChange)="startDate = toDate($event)"
```

I'm using Moment.js, which makes things MUCH easier:

my.component.ts

```js
...
import * as moment from 'moment';
...
@Component ({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  public fromDate: moment.Moment;
  public toDate: moment.Moment;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.toDate = moment();
    this.fromDate = moment().subtract(1, 'week');
  }

  dateStringToMoment(dateString: string): moment.Moment {
    return moment(dateString);
  }
```

my-component.html

```html
...
<input type="date" min="{{ fromDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" name="toDate" [ngModel]="toDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="toDate = dateStringToMoment($event)">
<input type="date" max="{{ toDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" name="fromDate" [ngModel]="fromDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="fromDate = dateStringToMoment($event)">
...
```

Comment: Merci pour la clarté de contenu

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it with this code:

```
handleEmployee(employee : Employee){
        this.employee = employee;

        let dateString : string = employee.startDate.toString();
        let days : number = parseInt(dateString.substring(8, 10));
        let months : number = parseInt(dateString.substring(5, 7));
        let years : number = parseInt(dateString.substring(0, 5));
        let goodDate : Date = new Date(years + "/" + months + "/" + days);
        goodDate.setDate(goodDate.getDate() + 2);
        this.date = goodDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    }
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <label>Start date: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="date" type="date" name="startDate"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a local string variable

```
dateField: string;
```

And I'm binding that to my form

Date input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="dateField" />
```

Later just assign that back to the Date property just before making any API call

```
insert() {
    this.myObjet.date = new Date(this.dateField);
    ... call api

update() {
    this.myObjet.date = new Date(this.dateField);
    ... call api
```