# Angular 2 Date Input not binding to date value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

trying to get a form set up but for some reason, the Date input in my html is not binding to the object's date value, despite using [(ngModel)]

html:

```
<input type='date' #myDate [(ngModel)]='demoUser.date'/><br>
```

form component:

```
export class FormComponent {
    demoUser = new User(0, '', '', '', '', new Date(), '', 0, [], []);  
}
```

User class:

```
export class User {
    constructor (
        public id: number,
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public date: Date,
        public gender: string,
        public weight: number,
        public dietRestrictions: string[],
        public fitnessGoals: string[]
    ){

    }
}
```

A test output reveals the current "new" Date as the object's value, but the input doesn't update the User object's date value or reflect the value, suggesting neither of the two-way bindings are working. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: How to use JavaScript Date Object with NgModel two way binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Instead of [(ngModel)] you can use:

```
// view
<input type="date" #myDate [value]="demoUser.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (input)="demoUser.date=parseDate($event.target.value)" />

// controller
parseDate(dateString: string): Date {
    if (dateString) {
        return new Date(dateString);
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can also choose not to use parseDate function. In this case the date will be saved as string format like "2016-10-06" instead of Date type (I haven't tried whether this has negative consequences when manipulating the data or saving to database for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot, used with small change: `(input)="demoUser.date = $event.target.valueAsDate"`

Comment: In this case its not possible to change the visible date from the component.

Answer (score 98):

**Angular 2 , 4 and 5** :

the simplest way : [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/s5OMg2olU2yHI246nJOG)

```
<input type="date" [ngModel] ="dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="dt = $event">
```

Comment: I like the simplicity and this is the simplest one. Thanks.

Comment: Quick and simple, but it throws localization out the window.

Comment: Great solution ! Thanks

Comment: what if I want dt to be of format 'dd-MM-yyyy', because $event is gives me date of format 'yyyy-MM-dd' even though I have set date pipe format to 'dd-MM-yyyy'

Comment: it's impossible to change the format. take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: Is there a way to do this if it is a form control?

Comment: Your solution has bugs. Click the x to clear the date, then click on mm and start typing the following sequence:  1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 0 - 1 - 7 to produce 11/11/2017 and the result is: mm/dd/0017, not 11/11/2017

Comment: Agreed with @alex on this one. Manually typed dates mess up with this method.

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine How should I use 'ngModel' if I am using FormControls in my template. It says I cannot use ngModel binding with FormControls.

Comment: it gives Error :Cannot have a pipe in an action expression

Comment: @Saurabh, please look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular

Comment: In the ngModelChange, you assign a string to the original dt variable which is supposed to be a Date object.

Answer (score 30):

In your component

```
let today: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

and in your html file

```
<input name="date" [(ngModel)]="today" type="date" required>
```

Comment: typescript will have design time warning for assigning string to Date

Comment: In my case, new Date(myDate).toISOString().split('T')[0] worked! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

In .ts :

```
today: Date;

constructor() {  

    this.today =new Date();
}
```

.html:

```
<input type="date"  
       [ngModel]="today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  
       (ngModelChange)="today = $event"    
       name="dt" 
       class="form-control form-control-rounded" #searchDate 
>
```

Comment: For some reason this is the only solution that works for me in Angular 15 (without using reactive forms)

Answer (score 8):

use **DatePipe**

```
> // ts file

import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
....
providers:[DatePipe]
})

export class FormComponent {

constructor(private datePipe : DatePipe){}

    demoUser = new User(0, '', '', '', '', this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '', 0, [], []);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Angular 2 completely ignores `type=date`. If you change type to `text` you'll see that your `input` has two-way binding.

```
<input type='text' #myDate [(ngModel)]='demoUser.date'/><br>
```

Here is pretty bad advise with better one to follow:

My project originally used `jQuery`. So, I'm using `jQuery datepicker` for now, hoping that angular team will fix the original issue. Also it's a better replacement because it has cross-browser support. FYI, `input=date` doesn't work in *Firefox*.

**Good advise**: There are few pretty good `Angular2 datepickers`:

- https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/tree/master/angular2-schedule/app/frontend/components/datepicker
- https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker

Comment: FYI: input=date works in Firefox 57+, but it does not work in IE or Safari. With IE still holding about 3% of browser usage, it's a bit of a headache still trying to support it at this point.

Answer (score 6):

As per HTML5, you can use
`input type="datetime-local"` 
instead of 
`input type="date"`.

It will allow the `[(ngModel)]` directive to read and write value from input control.

**Note:** If the date string contains 'Z' then to implement above solution, you need to trim the 'Z' character from date.

For more details, please go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) on mozilla docs.

Comment: `input type="date"` still works as well. It is supported in every browser except for IE and Safari. `type="datetime-local"` is a different input type altogether and is also not supported in Firefox: [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern browser there's a simple solution.

First, attach a template variable to the input.

```
<input type="date" #date />
```

Then pass the variable into your receiving method.

```
<button (click)="submit(date)"></button>
```

In your controller just accept the parameter as type HTMLInputElement
and use the method valueAsDate on the HTMLInputElement.

```
submit(date: HTMLInputElement){
    console.log(date.valueAsDate);
}
```

You can then manipulate the date anyway you would a normal date.

You can also set the value of your `<input [value]= "...">` as you
would normally.

Personally, as someone trying to stay true to the unidirectional data flow, i try to stay away from two way data binding in my components.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a workaround, like this:

```
<input type='date' (keyup)="0" #myDate [(ngModel)]='demoUser.date'/><br>
```

on your component :

```
 @Input public date: Date,
```

Comment: Could you please explain what (keyup) is doing?

Comment: angular only updates the screen, if we do this binding

source: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score -3):

In Typescript - app.component.ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    currentDate = new Date();
}
```

In HTML Input field

```
<input id="form21_1" type="text" tabindex="28" title="DATE" [ngModel]="currentDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" />
```

It will display the current date inside the input field.