# Angular2: Apply any property binding to child element

Tags: angular

Assume this simple Angular 2 app

Main component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app"
})
@View({
    directives: [ChildComponent]
    template: '<child-component></child-component>'
})
export class App {}
```

Child component

```
@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: '<input type="text" id="applyEverythingToMe" />'
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

How can we apply any property binding, directive, whatsoever to the `applyEverythingToMe` input field, without defining everything via `@Attribute`, ... in the ChildComponent?

Assume e.g. we want to disable the input via

```
<child-component [disabled]="true"></child-component>
```

The plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/kndYdGFsp8sEzCPpcKdq?p=preview

Edit:

As the first answers missed our actual problem, here is a bit more background:

We are using `<input type="date" />` and split up the banana-in-the-box into () and [] (e.g. described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890184/1256072).
This of course clutters every component with the parseDate, and it is also annoying that we cannot use `[(ngModel)]`.
As we did not find any way to extend the `ngModel` directive to e.g. `myModelDate` which automatically splits `[()]` and applies the parse method, we created our own component which implements `ControlValueAccessor` so we can bind it with `[(ngModel)]`. This components template only contains this one input type=date field. We now want our own component to behave just like any other input, so we can simply use `<my-date [disabled]="true"/>` or `<my-date [attr.whatever]="something" />` without explicitly defining all attributes via `@Input`, `@Attribute`, ...

Comment: I suggest you work through the Tour of Heroes tutorial and then re-ask the question if you still have it. The tutorial will answer that question for you--and many more.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I edited my initial question to give a bit more background what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: `@View({` was removed about 9 months ago. What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I find your question quite confusing and it's entirely unclear to me what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Input()` decorator on the properties that you want to expose in the child component.

For example:

```
import {Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: '<input type="text" />'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input disabled: boolean;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what we are trying to avoid.