# Date field not populating from database value Angular 12

Tags: html, angular

I am doing a Web Application which is used to manage a Company's Employees and Departments written in Angular 12.I have a date field(Date Of Joining) which needs to get pre-populated(from API) when we try to edit the Employee details. It is not working as it needs to be. Below is the program.

add-edit-emp.component.html

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">

<div class="form-froup row" style="width: 60%">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="from-control" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeName"
    placeholder="Enter Employee Name">
</div>

<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Department</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Department">
        <option>--Select--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let depName of DepartmentsList" >
            {{depName}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date Of Joining</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="DateOfJoining" value="{{DateOfJoining}}" 
     id="DateOfJoining" name="DateOfJoining">{{DateOfJoining}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <button (click)="addEmployee()" *ngIf="emp.EmployeeId==0" class="btn btn-primary">
  Add
 </button>
 <button (click)="updateEmployee()" *ngIf="emp.EmployeeId!=0" class="btn btn-primary">
  Update
 </button>
```

add-edit-emp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import  { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-add-edit-emp',
templateUrl: './add-edit-emp.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-edit-emp.component.css']
})
export class AddEditEmpComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

@Input() emp:any;
EmployeeId:string | undefined;
EmployeeName:string | undefined;
Department:string | undefined;
DateOfJoining:string | undefined;

DepartmentsList:any=[];


ngOnInit(): void {
this.loadDepartmentList();
}


loadDepartmentList(){
this.service.getAllDepartmentNames().subscribe((data:any) =>{
  
this.DepartmentsList= data;

this.EmployeeId = this.emp.EmployeeId;
this.EmployeeName = this.emp.EmployeeName;
this.Department = this.emp.Department;
this.DateOfJoining = this.emp.DateOfJoining;

 })
}


addEmployee(){
var val = {EmployeeId:this.EmployeeId,
             EmployeeName:this.EmployeeName,
              Department:this.Department,
               DateOfJoining:this.DateOfJoining,
             
 this.service.addEmployee(val).subscribe((res: { toString: () => any; }) =>{
   alert(res.toString());
 })              

 }

 updateEmployee(){
 var val = {EmployeeId:this.EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName:this.EmployeeName,
   Department:this.Department,
    DateOfJoining:this.DateOfJoining,
    this.service.updateEmployee(val).subscribe((res: { toString: () => any; })=>{
  alert(res.toString());
  })              

  }
  }
```

All the other values such as Employee Name ,Department are populated correctly. Only date field in not populating though I can just display the date next to date field.

can you help me where I am making a mistake. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Edit Employee modal]

Comment: Try selecting a date and see the value set in it and then try to bind that value in it. If it works then you might have to format the date before binding

Comment: Can you please check this link, It might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175251/angular-2-date-input-not-binding-to-date-value
check for @hakany's answer.. using input event is recommended over [(ngModel)] for date.