# how format date in [(ngModel)]?

Tags: angular

I tried to use - not working.

```
[ngModel]="user.date | date:'dd-MM-yy'"
```

I tried - not working:

```
[ngModel]="user.date.split("-").reverse().join('/')"
```

How can I treat date within [ngModel]?

Comment: what is the format you are getting?

Comment: is the user.date quite the date format？

Comment: I get the data with the format: "yy-MM-dd" and would like to turn: "dd/MM/yy" or "dd-MM-YY"

Comment: @Pengyy I tested the approach this link and did not work. Another issue is that Angled version 2 of this topic is outdated. I also found the polluted solution. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it. Thank you if you can help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: How to use JavaScript Date Object with NgModel two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding)