# Angular 2 http.post not working with web api

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-post

My Web Api Core Controller Method looks like this

```
public void Post(Sample sample) {
         _sampleService.CreateSample(sample);
    }
```

Sample POCO looks like this

```
  public class Sample : BaseEntity
{
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

on the client side sample object is only sending 2 properties for now and looks like this.

```
{barcode:"1234"createdAt:"2017-06-07"}
```

and the http post looks like this

```
createSample(sample: Sample) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post(AppConstants.createSample, JSON.stringify(sample), { headers: headers })
  .map((res: Response) => res.json());  }
```

so if i user headers i get  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

if i not use headers i get (Unsupported Media Type)

any idea whats going on here. 
**UPDATE**
so I followed instructions as in first answer and looks like CORS is not set property but now JSON is not being converted to C# Object
[image]

Comment: Looks like a CORS problem.

Comment: Not a CORS issue rest of calls are working. CORS was enabled globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use headers to tell the API method what you're sending.
2. You need to enable CORS in your .Net Core app `Startup.cs` so that your API allows requests coming from another origin (accepts calls from your client app url, basically) - and set CORS to **AllowAnyMethod()**

You do this with the following code in your `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
var corsUrls = new List<string>(){"http://localhost:4200", "https://mylivesite.com"};

services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
      .AllowAnyMethod() //<--this allows preflight headers required for POST
      .AllowAnyHeader() //<--accepts headers 
      .AllowCredentials() //<--lets your app send auth credentials
      .WithOrigins(corsUrls.ToArray()); //<--this is the important line
}));

services.Configure<MvcOptions>(
    options => { options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("CorsPolicy")); });
```

and then finally in your `Configure()` method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Note that the policy name `"CorsPolicy"` that I've used is just an example, you can call it whatever you like.

Comment: Will try this in couple of minutes

Comment: This is a mapping problem between your client and server - my guess is that its because your cases dont match and you havent set the following after you call services.AddMvc(...) `mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(
                    x => x.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());`

Comment: as its mvc core so i tried 

services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())

but it looks like by just adding [FromBody] in post method it works but only through PostMan

from Angular app it still getting null. 
It works fine if i use dynamic or JObject

Comment: Possibly data type related then. The conversion from partial JSON object to your POCO might be invalid - try making a simpler class (string type properties are simplest to start with) and use that - if it works, then change one property type at a time until it stops working - then you know where the problem is.

Comment: So the problem is that if my typescript object contains date it becomes null on server side. For example of i have datetimr propery in POCO and createdAt: Date in my typescript object , it doesn't work

Comment: Here's how to fix that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491938/issues-with-date-when-using-json-stringify-and-json-parse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding/37055451#37055451

this answer also helped as this was a form . 
its working now

Thankyou very much :)