# Angular2 Date control HTML5

Tags: html, angular

I am having issues with angular2 and HTML5 input="date"

in my form if i do the following 
[(ngModel)]="certification.issueDate" 
i can pick and save the date, but can not show a date already saved

if i do the following in form
[value]="certification.issueDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"

I can show a currently saved date but can not save a new date

i have read that i should do this
[(ngModel)]="certification.issueDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" without the [value]="certification.issueDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"

but this causes an error of the following:

compiler.es5.js:12932 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 27 in [certification.issueDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'=$event] in ng:///AppModule/CertificationComponent.html@56:67 (">
        
            Issued Date: ][(ngModel)]="certification.issueDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
                 class="form-control" name="issuedDate""): ng:///AppModule/CertificationComponent.html@56:67

Not sure what I am missing... I'm sure it is something simple.  But being new to Angular I'm now stuck

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding

Comment: Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GUnusYHupP4BJjLSQltn?p=preview), cheers!!