# Angular Date Binding on Form Off by One on Submit

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, javascript-databinding

I'm attempting to display a saved date on a form using an approach that is much like two-way binding for Angular using `[ngModel]`, but **not `[(ngModel)]`** utilizing a solution I found on a similar stack overflow question/answer.

However, when I go to save, the date that saves and displays is off by one. For example, if I save using html date input format `07/04/2021 (July 4, 2021)` it ends up saving on the form on submit as: `07/03/2021` (the classic off by one error). Below is my code that I took from a previous stack overflow answer. I'm using mongoDB with a typical USER object with a `dateOfBirth` (Date type) attribute for the date.

```html
<input
   class="form-control"
   id="dateOfBirth"
   type="date"
   name="dateOfBirth"
   placeholder="date"
   [ngModel]="user.dateOfBirth | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
   (ngModelChange)="user.dateOfBirth = $event"
/>
```

The first approach I tried:
[Angular 2: How to use JavaScript Date Object with NgModel two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055311/angular-2-how-to-use-javascript-date-object-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding)

Comment: Could this be a timezone problem? Try adding timezone information to your DataPipe.

Comment: I want to display the date in MM/DD/YYYY format on the form field. Won't adding timezone information change the way it's displayed? Plus, am I using the DatePipe only for the input and not the output?